# Using Model Field Values inside Model.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have Model in django and I wanna use username value inside this Account Model to Address ImageField
How can I do that?

```
class Account(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70)

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = f'userdata/{username}/avatar/' ,default= MEDIA_ROOT + 'default/img/avatar.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Work with a callable:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70)

    def avatar_path(self, filename):
        return f'userdata/{self.username}/avatar/{filename}'

    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=avatar_path, default=MEDIA_ROOT + 'default/img/avatar.png'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use upload_to as callable, such as a function.

For reference check this [gfg](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/imagefield-django-models/) page

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return f'userdata/{instance.username}/avatar/{filename}'

class Account(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70)

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, default=MEDIA_ROOT + 'default/img/avatar.png')
```